# Get a reference to an object with his name c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I Have a wpf `UserControl` with some shapes into it like this.

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid Name="Contenedor1" Height="299.814" Width="238.429" 
        <Path x:Name="_1_2" Data=""/>
        <Path x:Name="_1_3" Data=""/>
        <Path x:Name="_1_4" Data=""/>
        <Path x:Name="_1_5" Data=""/>
        <Path x:Name="_1_6" Data=""/>
        <Path x:Name="_1_7" Data=""/>
        <Path x:Name="_1_8" Data=""/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I want in my code behind get a reference to one path by hisname, at one procces i get the number of the shape `1 2 3 ... n` and formating it properly I get the corresponding object name, something like: if i get `3`, the object name is `_1_3`.

Now I get the name, and  need a reference to my `shape` to make it some changes. How can i do to get this reference at my code behind

Comment: When did references acquire a gender ("his")?

Comment: You have not posted valid XAML. You're missing a right angle bracket.

Comment: @Andrew Yes sorry for my english, think now it is ok.

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez No worries, I kind of like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`FrameworkElement.FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find the proper Path:

```
// In code behind
var element = 3; // You say you already have this
var name = "_1_" + element.ToString();

Path path = this.FindName(name) as Path;
if (path != null)
{
   // use path
}
```